# Server side processing Jquery Datatables Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, sharepoint-online

I have a >50000 SharePoint Online document library list being rendered using the working code below. The page load time is close to 10-15 seconds.

I tried to implement server side processing to reduce page load times, but it made no difference:

`"processing": true, "serverSide": true,`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html">    
<head>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<SPO_SITE>/SiteAssets/js/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<SPO_SITE>/SiteAssets/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<SPO_SITE>/SiteAssets/js/moment.min.js"></script>     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<SPO_SITE>/SiteAssets/js/datetime-moment.js"></script>      
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<SPO_SITE>/SiteAssets/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>       
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<SPO_SITE>/SiteAssets/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>            
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<SPO_SITE>/SiteAssets/js/jszip.min.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<SPO_SITE>/SiteAssets/js/pdfmake.min.js"></script>      
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<SPO_SITE>/SiteAssets/js/vfs_fonts.js"></script>            
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<SPO_SITE>/SiteAssets/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<SPO_SITE>/SiteAssets/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<SPO_SITE>/SiteAssets/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<SPO_SITE>/SiteAssets/js/dataTables.searchBuilder.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<SPO_SITE>/SiteAssets/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<SPO_SITE>/SiteAssets/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css">      
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<SPO_SITE>/SiteAssets/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<SPO_SITE>/SiteAssets/css/select.dataTables.min.css">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<SPO_SITE>/SiteAssets/css/searchBuilder.dataTables.min.css">  

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {loadItems();});    

function loadItems() {    
    var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;    
    var oDataUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('LIST_NAME')/items?$top=200000&$select=Created,ATA,EncodedAbsUrl";    
    $.ajax({    
        url: oDataUrl,    
        type: "GET",    
        dataType: "json",    
        headers: {    
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"    
        },    
        success: mySuccHandler,    
        error: myErrHandler    
    });    
}    
  
function mySuccHandler(data) {    
    try {    
          
        $('#table_id').DataTable({    
            "pageLength": 100,
            "dom": 'Bfrtip',
            "buttons": [ {extend: 'searchBuilder', config: {columns: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],},}, 'copy', 'csv', 'pdf', {extend: 'print',exportOptions: {columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]}} ],
            "aaData": data.d.results,
            "aaSorting": [[0, "desc"]],
            "aoColumns": [  
            {    
                "mData": "Created"
            },             
            {    
                "mData": "ATA"    
            },             
            {    
                "mData": "EncodedAbsUrl",
                "mRender": function ( data, type, full )
                {return '<a href="'+data+'" target="_blank">View</a>';}             
            }
            ]    
        });    
    } catch (e) {    
        alert(e.message);    
    }    
}    
    
function myErrHandler(data, errMessage) {    
    alert("Error: " + errMessage);    
}   
</script>

</head>    
<body>    
   <div> 
    <table id="table_id" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">    
        <thead>    
            <tr>    
                <th>Uploaded</th>    
                <th>ATA</th>
                <th></th>           
            </tr>    
        </thead>    
    </table>    
    </div>    
</body>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set backend code because serverside means you have to handle Datatable rows on server on each action on client side (change page , filter , search , ...)

For more informations here : https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side

Comment: Agreed, any pointer on how to do this with sharepoint?

Comment: Add the word cache to your query/search for answers.  There are many different kinds of caches and tricks to make them most efficient.

Comment: hi Nasandrata, since this data is dynamic and fed from a SPO rest api xml feed with over 50k entries, i guess cache wouldn't be the most appropriate?

Comment: You don't have to load 50k entries at the same time, you have to paginate your datatable and load only 10 entries,that's serverside means,and when your change page or do filter or search, you fetch another 10 entries based on conditions you set. Take a look at the link i gave before and click on serverside script, you have to code the PHP code to sharepoint code.